# python function only returns the first element of the first sublist

Tags: python, list, function, sublist

I want to print all elements of all sublists which I am able to do with the following loop

```
sublists=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 7, 7]]
for i in sublists:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

but if I use this function, it only prints the first item of the first sublist.
Why is that? How do I make this function work ?

```
def sl_check(sl):
    for i in sl:
        for j in i:
            return j
print(sl_check(sublists))
```

Comment: Hi, after the return your function doesn't execute anymore, this means only once

Comment: If you want to create an iterable object, you can use ```yield``` instead of ```return```. If you want to create a list, use the ```append()``` method

Comment: yield returns teh following <generator object sl_check at 0x00000211C05A0CF0> how to use yield to return the sublists ?

Answer (score 0):

The `return` breaks out of the loop, so you'll need to collect all the elements in a new list and then return everything outside the loop:

```py
def sl_check(sl):
    all_elements = []
    for i in sl:
        for j in i:
            all_elements.append(j)
    return all_elements

sublists=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 7, 7]]
print(sl_check(sublists))
```