# is there a way to make the for loop here return the value for each item on the same line

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

The below code is what im trying to have the for loop iterate and return a value for each item:

```py
def number(lines):
    #your code here
    c=0
    for i in lines:
        return'[{}:{}]'.format(str(c+1),i) 

print(number(['a','b','c']))
```

so i placed in the code and was expecting it to return `['1:a','2:b','3:c']`
but it just returns `['1:a']`

Comment: Do you understand what `return` does? Why do you expect your function to continue running after you `return` at the end of the first loop?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71263926/python-function-only-returns-the-first-element-of-the-first-sublist

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems:

- You use `return` in the first iteration of your loop
- You are not incrementing your variable `c`

This will work:

```py
def number(lines):
    c = 1
    return_value = []
    for line in lines:
        return_value.append('[{}:{}]'.format(str(c),line))
        c += 1
    return return_value

print(number(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

An alternative would be

```py
def number(lines): 
    return ['[{}:{}]'.format(str(c), line) for c, line in enumerate(lines,1)]

print(number(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```